# Hosting provider says website email form must be smtp for security reasons not php script

Tags: php, email, smtp

I try to set my php mail script to SMTP mail script beacuse my hosting provider does not allow to send mails without verifiny.
My visitors send emails from my website to my domain email account.
I have to send SMTP mail but i could not transform that script to php mail form.
Here is the code below:

```
<?    
if($_POST[CheckTavsiye]=='Evet')    
{     
$Kactive = '1';    
$body ="Full Name:  ".$_POST['name']." ".$_POST['surname']."\n";    
$body .="Email  : ".$_POST['email']."\n";    
$body .="Phone number : ".$_POST['phone']."\n";    
$body .="Property No:   ".$_POST['pno']."\n";    
$body .="Country : ".$_POST['country']."\n";    
$body .="Comments :   ".$_POST['mortgage']."\n";    
$from       ="example<info@domain.com>";    
$to         ="info@domain.com";    
$subject    ="example";    
$as_from    ="example<info@domain.com>";    
$as_to      = $_POST['email'];    
$as_subject ="example";    
$as_body    = "Hi,    

Your enquiry has been received. 

";    

include("mailsend.php");    
?>
```

Script and files provided by hosting:

- index.html
- send.php
- include folder (class.php, smtp.php)

Here is the code below: send.php

```
<?php    

$mail_adress    = "";    
$mail_password  = "";    
$send_adress    = "";    
$domain_adress  = "";   //without the www    

require("include/class.php");    
$mail = new PHPMail();    
$mail->Host       = "smtp.".$domain_adress;    
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;    
$mail->Username   = $mail_adress;    
$mail->Password   = $mail_password;    
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->AddAddress($send_adreds);    
$mail->From       = $mail_adress;    
$mail->FromName   = $mail_adress;    
$mail->Subject    = $_POST["MailSubject"];    
$mail->Body       = $_POST["mailadress"]."\n".$_POST["Mail"];    
$mail->AltBody    = "";    

if(!$mail->Send()){    
echo "<html>\n";    
echo "<head>\n";    
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Language\" content=\"tr\">\n";    
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1254\">\n";    
echo "<meta name=\"Author\" content=\"IsimTescil Destek\">\n";    
echo "<title> IsimTescil - Destek </title>\n";    
echo "</head>\n";    
echo "<body>\n";    
echo "<center>\n";    
echo "<hr width=\"500\" color=\"#C0C0C0\" style=\"border-style: double; border-width: 3px\">\n";    
echo "<font face=\"Verdana\" style=\"font-size: 8pt\"><b>[</b> <font color=\"#0000FF\">\n";    
echo "Mesajýnýz Gönderilirken bir hata oluþtu. Sunucudan gelen cevap aþaðýdaki gibidir:\n";    
echo "</font> <b>]</b></font>\n";    
echo "<br><font face=\"Verdana\" style=\"font-size: 8pt\"><b>[</b> <font color=\"#0000FF\">\n";    
echo "Hata: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;    
echo "</font> <b>]</b></font>\n";    
echo "<hr width=\"500\" color=\"#C0C0C0\" style=\"border-style: double; border-width: 3px\">\n";    
echo "</center>\n";    
echo "</body>\n";    
echo "</html>\n";    
exit;    
}    

echo "<html>\n";    
echo "<head>\n";    
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Language\" content=\"tr\">\n";    
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1254\">\n";
echo "<meta name=\"Author\" content=\"IsimTescil Destek\">\n";    
echo "<title> IsimTescil - Destek </title>\n";    
echo "</head>\n";    
echo "<body>\n";    
echo "<center>\n";    
echo "<hr width=\"500\" color=\"#C0C0C0\" style=\"border-style: double; border-width: 3px\">\n";    
echo "<font face=\"Verdana\" style=\"font-size: 8pt\"><b>[</b> <font color=\"#0000FF\">\n";    
echo "Mesajýnýz Gönderilmiþtir.\n";    
echo "</font> <b>]</b></font>\n";    
echo "<hr width=\"500\" color=\"#C0C0C0\" style=\"border-style: double; border-width: 3px\">\n";    
echo "</center>\n";    
echo "</body>\n";    
echo "</html>\n";    

?>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. i have copy / paste the codes above in enquire.php..... but still when the website email form is filled out and hit send, the website form says email is sent with no error..., but no email comes to inbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use phpmailer for SMTP email sending:

This configuration for gmail in PHP mailer. You can create SMTP configuration like this.

```
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;
//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```